# php select limited amount of data from table and order by date for lazy loading

Tags: php

I am using lazy loading to load data from database to device the limit is 20
but my problem lies when I pull the data from table because I have to order it by latest next date.

eg. I pull all data for today then tommorrow and then so on
I cant use the id to keep track of what I loaded becuase the entries have different dates when entered

this is and example of my table. please note that my table can have thousands of entries

```
|  id   | name  |    date    |   time   |
|   0   | name1 | 2018-09-30 | 01:00:00 |
|   1   | name2 | 2019-01-10 | 15:30:00 |
|   2   | name3 | 2019-09-30 | 10:20:00 |
|   3   | name4 | 2018-05-20 | 14:10:00 |
|   4   | name5 | 2020-09-02 | 01:30:00 |
|   5   | name6 | 2018-10-30 | 14:00:00 |
```

this is what my sql php script looks like. I know its not right but its an example of what im triying to do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '$today' AND id >= '$lastId' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 20
```

as you can see the id increments but the dates dont increment because it can be entered with any future date.
I apologize for my bad english. Please can anyone help me

Comment: Do you mean **Pagination** rather than Lazy Loading

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i mean that. I only want to load a few at a time and keep track of what has been laoded so I dont load it again

Comment: Then forget about `id` the normal way is to use the `LIMIT start_from_row, 20` and you keep a track of where you are in the paginator by remembering where you were last

Comment: @RiggsFolly I see what you I mean I will try that. thanks for quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to paginate : you can use php or ajax and the last's is recommended:

```
<?php

$limit = 2;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field ASC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);  
?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
<thead>  
<tr>  
<th>title</th>  
<th>body</th>  
</tr>  
</thead>  
<tbody>  
<?php  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {  
?>  
            <tr>  
            <td><? echo $row["field"]; ?></td>  

            </tr>  
<?php  
};  
?>  
</tbody>  
</table>
```

finally add this to your html code:

Comment: Using `mysql_query` is not recommended for a very long time now.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. @Volvox I will be using mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: it work for me for a project in unversity but php is released now ,update as you can ,thank's